# Symmetric points in $\overline{\mathbb C}$ problem

Tags: complex-analysis

Statement
Let $z_1,z_2,z_ 3$ be three distinct points in $\overline{\mathbb C}$, show that there is a unique line or circle $C$  such that $z_1 \in C$, and $z_2$ and $z_3$ are symmetric with respect to $C$.

I need help to solve this problem (maybe hints or ideas), I would appreciate suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Möbius transformation $T$ to move $z_1$ to $\infty$.  Then the problem is just finding a unique perpendicular bisector of $T(z_2)$ and $T(z_3)$, which we know we can do.  Apply the inverse of $T$ to return to the original configuration.

Comment: Let me see if I get this: You are suggesting me to consider the line $L$ which is the perpendicular bisector of $T(z_2)$ and $T(z_3)$ and to send $z_1$ to $L$ so $T(z_1) \in L$. As Möbius transformations preserve symmetry and the usual definiton of symmetry about a line coincides with this definition of symmetry, then $z_2$ and $z_3$ are symmetric with respecto to $T^{-1}(L)$ and $z_1 \in T^{-1}(L)$. There are still two doubts I have: 1) how do I know $T^{-1}(L)$ is a line or a circle and how can I prove uniqueness?

Comment: @user100106 The image of a line under a Möbius transformation is either a line or a circle.  Uniqueness follows from the fact that the perpendicular bisector between 2 points is unique.